# JsonModel Mapping Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-coding, jsonmodel

I am using jsonmodel for mapping my response after getting from my service. Now the problems my service is giving me the response as an array of dictionaries but I can't map the array as it is not assigned against any key.

[image]

I have a JsonModel named ContactsModel.h which hold all the parameters identifier which mapped perfectly, but then I need to take the array of this model.
So, I created another JsonModel, ContactListModel to hold that.

```
#import <JSONModel/JSONModel.h>
#import "ContactsModel.h"

@interface ContactListModel : JSONModel

@property(nonatomic, assign) NSArray<ContactsModel> *contacts;

@end
```

But see, my array is not assigned against any key. So, I think, that is why it is not being able to map.

Cane anyone please help me to deal with this situation.

Comment: I see you are getting an array of dictionaries in response, what issue you are facing?

Comment: any errors? just no data?

Comment: The response object is an array of dictionaries which is cool but the fact is that array is not assigned against any key. So, I can't do key-value pairing.

Comment: Can u add the declaration of `ContactsModel` I think there must be something wrong inside. Or there should be an error given by JSONModel when you create the `contract` using the `NSString`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray new];

for(NSDictionary *dictionary in responseObject){
[objects addObject:dictionary];
//do your modeling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@natasha

I do think you can use JSONModel's method `arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:`

So in your request you can do something like this:

```
 NetworkRequest:<whatEverRequest> params:<whatEverParams> completion:(id response){

if([response isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){

  ContactListModel *list = [ContactListModel new];
  list.contacts = [ContactsModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries: response];
   // I just followed the jsonModel API. maybe latest version has initWithArray? 
}

} error:(NSError *error){}];
```

I hope this solves your problem